# catkin_make erorr, I have removed some un-used files then I got trouble with catkin_make any one can help me plz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

abdulrahman@abdulrahman-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/abdulrahman/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/abdulrahman/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/abdulrahman/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/abdulrahman/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/abdulrahman/catkin_ws/install

##### Running command: "cmake /home/abdulrahman/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/abdulrahman/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/abdulrahman/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/abdulrahman/catkin_ws/build"

-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/abdulrahman/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/abdulrahman/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.6
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 22 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - camera_umd (metapackage)
-- ~~  - freenect_launch
-- ~~  - freenect_stack
-- ~~  - iai_kinect2 (metapackage)
-- ~~  - image_common (metapackage)
-- ~~  - openni2_launch
-- ~~  - camera_calibration_parsers
-- ~~  - kinect2_registration
-- ~~  - image_transport
-- ~~  - camera_info_manager
-- ~~  - jpeg_streamer
-- ~~  - openni_launch
-- ~~  - polled_camera
-- ~~  - freenect_camera
-- ~~  - openni_camera
-- ~~  - find_object_2d
-- ~~  - kinect2_bridge
-- ~~  - kinect2_calibration
-- ~~  - kinect2_viewer
-- ~~  - denso_gui
-- ~~  - usb_cam
-- ~~  - uvc_camera
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'camera_umd'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(camera_umd-master/camera_umd)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'freenect_launch'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(freenect_stack/freenect_launch)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'freenect_stack'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(freenect_stack/freenect_stack)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'iai_kinect2'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(iai_kinect2/iai_kinect2)
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'image_common'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(image_common/image_common)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'openni2_launch'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(openni2_launch)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'camera_calibration_parsers'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(image_common/camera_calibration_parsers)
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   python
--   system
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'kinect2_registration'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(iai_kinect2/kinect2_registration)
-- Could NOT find OpenCL (missing:  OpenCL_LIBRARY OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- CPU based depth registration enabled
-- OpenCL based depth registration disabled
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'image_transport'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(image_common/image_transport)
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'camera_info_manager'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(image_common/camera_info_manager)
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'jpeg_streamer'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(camera_umd-master/jpeg_streamer)
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'openni_launch'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(openni_launch)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'polled_camera'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(image_common/polled_camera)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- polled_camera: 0 messages, 1 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'freenect_camera'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(freenect_stack/freenect_camera)
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"diagnostic_updater" with any of the following names:

```
diagnostic_updaterConfig.cmake
diagnostic_updater-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "diagnostic_updater" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "diagnostic_updater_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
files.  If "diagnostic_updater" provides a separate development package or
SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
freenect_stack/freenect_camera/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)

-- Could not find the required component 'diagnostic_updater'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"diagnostic_updater" with any of the following names:

```
diagnostic_updaterConfig.cmake
diagnostic_updater-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "diagnostic_updater" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "diagnostic_updater_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
files.  If "diagnostic_updater" provides a separate development package or
SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
freenect_stack/freenect_camera/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/abdulrahman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/abdulrahman/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
abdulrahman@abdulrahman-ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:~/catkin_ws$

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262220/catkin_make-erorr,-i-have-removed-some-un-used-files-then-i-got-trouble-with-catkin_make-any-one-can-help-me-plz/) by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-05-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) on 2017-05-22**:
did you delete the build and devel folders after removing these files? You should delete them in order to do a clean catkin_make.

**Comment by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on 2017-05-22**:
yes i already did, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error message tells you that the ROS Package diagnostic_updater is missing.

There can be some reasons for that:

1. Is your workspace sourced correctly?
2. Is your ROS Distro sourced correctly?
3. When you compile it from source are your dependencies set correctly?

If its even not installed I think you just can

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-diagnostics
```

Than the package which is missing is installed.

---

Originally posted by [chwimmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/21005/chwimmer/) with karma: 436 on 2017-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on 2017-05-22**:
thx to ur reply, it works now, the problem was that I wanted to fee up some space in ubuntu, I have used bleachbit, then it seems I removed some important files. Finally, I was trying this code in terminal [sudo apt-get install ros_kinetic_diagnostics], but it doesn't work, then I used yours, thx